# Why is my program slower, despite using more threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am new to *threading* , and I wanted to test my newly acquired skills, with a simple task, create an image using *multiple threads*, the interesting part is that , **on a single thread , the program runs faster , than using 4 threads** (which is my most efficient, parallel thread runnning capacity I believe ) I have an i3 processor,using ubuntu 17,and my **std::thread::hardware_concurrency is 4**.
my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <png++/png.hpp>
#include <time.h>

std::vector<int> bounds(int max, int parts)
{
    std::vector<int> interval;
    int gap = max / parts;
    int left = max % parts;
    int nr1 = 0;
    int nr2;

    interval.push_back(nr1);
    for (int i = 0; i < parts; i++)
    {
        nr2 = nr1 + gap;
        if (i == parts - 1)
            nr2 += left;
        nr1 = nr2;
        interval.push_back(nr2);
    }
    return interval;
}

void create_image(png::image<png::rgb_pixel> &image, int start, int end)
{
    std::mutex my_mutex;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(my_mutex);
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < image.get_height(); j++)
            image[i][j] = png::rgb_pixel(rand() % 256, 0, rand() % 256);
}

int main()
{
    png::image<png::rgb_pixel> png_image(6000, 6000);                  //Creating Image
    int parts = 1;                                                     //amount of parallel threads
    std::vector<int> my_vector = bounds(png_image.get_width(), parts); //interval vector
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;                                  //threads

    time_t start, end;
    time(&start); //measuring time
    for (int i = 0; i < parts - 1; i++)
    {
        workers.push_back(std::thread(create_image, std::ref(png_image), my_vector[i], my_vector[i + 1]));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < parts - 1; i++)
        workers[i].join();

    create_image(png_image, my_vector[parts - 1], my_vector[parts]);

    png_image.write("test.png");
    time(&end);
    std::cout << (end - start) << " seconds\n";

    return 0;
}
```

To build this, run `g++ file.cpp -o test -lpng -pthread` (with [png++](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pngpp/)).

Comment: Mutexs cause serialization.

Comment: but if i remove the mutex, isn't there a chance that some changes won't be recorded ? since they share the same resource ?**EDIT**:removing the mutex didn't change the fact, that it is still slower with more threads :(

Comment: how much memory do those PNG take up? e.g. are the multiple threads thrashing the memory cache, or ... ?

Comment: 85,2 MB, I am not sure what do you mean by "Trashing the memory cache" but if you are refering to segmentation fault , then no , this code works, but not as I wanted it to work ( which was to make a comparsion, of different thread amounts and run-time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mutex is a red herring -- it is local to the function, and so it's not actually locking anything since there ends up being a separate mutex for each thread. In order to actually lock, you would need to move the mutex variable out of create_image.

However, the writes to the image are independent, so it locking isn't actually needed. That is, since each call to create_image is to a separate region, the writes do not overlap. You guarantee the changes will be recorded by joining the threads to wait for their completion.

The problem is actually rand(). From my testing, it has its own internal mutex locking which is causing all the slowdown. Changing from rand() to rand_r(&seed) makes all the difference. The more threads in use, the more expensive the locking becomes (per call), and so you see a slowdown.

Having said that, on my CPU, the creation of the PNG is the dominant cost in this program. Without writing the PNG image, the program runs in under 2s (single thread) and scales nearly linearly with the number of cores used. With writing the PNG image, that time jumps to over 8s, so writing the PNG image is taking much longer than creating the image.

Here is what I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <png++/png.hpp>
#include <time.h>

std::vector<int> bounds(int max, int parts)
{
    std::vector<int> interval;
    int gap = max / parts;
    int left = max % parts;
    int nr1 = 0;
    int nr2;

    interval.push_back(nr1);
    for (int i = 0; i < parts; i++)
    {
        nr2 = nr1 + gap;
        if (i == parts - 1)
            nr2 += left;
        nr1 = nr2;
        interval.push_back(nr2);
    }
    return interval;
}

void create_image(png::image<png::rgb_pixel> &image, int start, int end)
{
    unsigned int seed = time(NULL);
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < image.get_height(); j++)
            image[i][j] = png::rgb_pixel(rand_r(&seed) % 256, 0, rand_r(&seed) % 256);
}

int main()
{
    png::image<png::rgb_pixel> png_image(6000, 6000);                  //Creating Image
    int parts = 1;                                                     //amount of parallel threads
    std::vector<int> my_vector = bounds(png_image.get_width(), parts); //interval vector
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;                                  //threads

    time_t start, end;
    time(&start); //measuring time
    for (int i = 0; i < parts; i++)
    {
        workers.push_back(std::thread(create_image, std::ref(png_image), my_vector[i], my_vector[i + 1]));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < parts; i++)
        workers[i].join();

    png_image.write("test.png");
    time(&end);
    std::cout << (end - start) << " seconds\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You ! Can I ask you from where does one know such deep things ?I would also love to deepen my knowledge!

Comment: Long experience and an in-depth knowledge of how CPUs work. I'd suggest looking into courses on computer architecture and parallel processing.